# Make Print button in Node Js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, pdf, printing

I currently work on invoice system in Node Js and MySql database.

How i can do when invoice complete after that click button **(button name = Create)** and than invoice convert into custom style pdf and print that pdf?

**Note: pdf don't store in any directory & database. Also when click button (button name = Create) don't open print dialog box just directly invoice print out in custom style pdf from connected printer.**

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend building up an html page with the data that you want and using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2pdf.js/v/0.9.0) utility to output to a PDF.